# Make a div, containing an img draggable

Tags: css, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm trying to make a `div` draggable. The `div` contains an `img` and some text that serves as a label for the image. The problem is that when I start the drag by clicking on the `img`, the `img` gets dragged, and not the parent `div`. How do I fix that?

```html
<div className="container-selected" id={id} draggable="true" onDragStart={this.dragStart} onDragEnd={this.drop} onClick={this.click}>
  <img src={imgSrc} />
  <span className="item-id">Some text</span>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```css
.container-selected {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;

  img {
    width: 3em;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  .item-id {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top:  53px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is many years later, but I ran into the same problem, and finally figured it out.

An image is draggable by default, so when you drag an image in a div, the image gets dragged. All you have to do is the make the image non-draggable by:

```
<img draggable="false" src={status} />
```

Now when you drag the div, the div and its contained image are dragged together.

Comment: Thank you, I run into the same issue and got crazy :-) This is definitively the good answer.

Comment: Very useful! I was looking for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5's drag and drop like this: https://jsfiddle.net/bv5fLrth/23/

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div> 

<div id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">

<img id="drag1" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
</div>
<script>
  function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }

  function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  }

  function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }

</script>
```

Comment: OK, that's basically what I was doing, but you assign the same id to the div and the img. That pretty much does the job. The only thing is that the object that you drag looks different depending on whether you drag the image or the label, but that's really minor. Thanks Adam!

Comment: @DmitryShvedov I am sure there is a better way of doing it, that will fix that problem, hopefully someone else answers the question too with a better idea.